# Python subprocess.Popen error handling with shell=True/False issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen, ioerror

I am trying to get some error handling for the following code.

In the line subprocess.Popen...... if the shell=True the script will encrypt if a correct file name is given, however there is no file with that name the error code is not printed, but it does show on terminal as no existing file/directory.

if I run the shell=False then I am not able to encrypt files but the error message does print.

Would it be possible for anyone to explain what I am doing wrong? As I have looked at different posts on here but I still do not understand why it won't work. My guess is that it has something to do with the shell=True portion of the script.

SrcDIR ="/home/test/testsource/"

DstDIR ="/home/test/testdest/"

```
try:
    subprocess.Popen(["openssl aes-128-cbc -salt -in " + SrcDIR + str(var1) + " -out " + DstDIR + "enc." + str() + " -k " + str(var2)], shell=True)
    output3 = ("file " + str(var1) + "created")
    print(output3)
except IOError as reason2:
    errormsg = ("Error encrypting file due to: \n" + str(reason2))
    print(errormsg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the `shell` arg to `False`, then the `args` argument becomes a *sequence* of strings, not a single string: the first `args` element is the name of the program to run, and subsequent elements are the arguments to that program, *e.g.* (if I understand your code correctly):

```
subprocess.Popen \
  (
    [
        "openssl", "aes-128-cbc", "-salt",
        "-in", os.path.join(SrcDIR, var1),
        "-out", os.path.join(DstDIR, "enc." + var1),
        "-k", var2
    ]
  )
```

This is also better than trying to pass a single command string with `shell` = `True`, because this way you don’t have to beware of characters with special meaning to the shell.

Comment: Thank you for your help, now I am able to run the encryption portion with   shell=False. However, I am still having issues with the error checking. As even if the file does not exist the subprocess will still execute and print file created. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try the `subprocess.check_output` convenience routine, which creates the Popen object, collects its output and checks for errors, all in one go.

Comment: Or if you don’t want the output from the command, use `subprocess.check_call` instead.

Comment: Hey, another quick question if you have time. Would it be possible to use subprocess.check_output to return an error code for an if statement? Such as if subprocess.check_output == error code 0 or something along those lines. Essentially if there is an error then output the error reasoning, and if there isn't an error then proceed and execute the subprocess.Popen.

Comment: If the subprocess prints out any error messages, then presumably the user will see that. Is that what you mean by “reasoning”?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean as error reasoning.

Comment: Hey, just wanted to say thank you again. Found out I can use CalledErrorProcess and it does exactly what I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

Even with shell=True, if the first parameter is a list of strings, it will interpret that as a list of arguments for the call.  There are other reasons one might not want to use shell=True, but needing to not use shell=True to use a list of arguments is not one of them.

Other than that point, Lawrence D'Oliveiro is correct in regards to the benefits of using a list vs a single string.